# call a phone number plugin for wp8 platform cordova

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, plugins

I am searching for a call phone number plugin for wp8 platform of cordova.
Can anyone help ? Suggest me with the available plugins.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Calling a single number?

Comment: @Beat :- yes , i have  list of contact profiles which has a call number option  when clicked , it should open a default  dialog box  of windows phone to call a number

Comment: function callTelephone(phone,name){

 console.log(name+"  " + phone);
    var arr = new Array();
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.chemistName = ""+name;
    obj.phoneNumber = "" + phone;
   
    arr.push(obj);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
 
     var callmyno=navigator.plugins['MyPlugin'];

      callmyno.callFunction(success, fail, arr);
             
   
        
}  here,  the callFunction is not getting called . its is defined in the .cs file of a plugin named as 'myplugin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put in your `html` template file a `href` tag which is referencing the related telephone number, for example like:

```
<div id="telephone-list">
    <a href="tel:0123456789">Call me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I upvoted the answer, I'm not sure if I can mark it as accepted as I had not asked the question originally.

Comment: Oh I did not see...I'm sorry

Comment: @Beat : how to assign the telephone which is coming from database on local storage of windows phone 8 , something like this :  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" ng-click="callNumber(contactData.m_mobile_no1)"><p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone ftBtns"></i> Call</p></div>

Comment: i am using angular js, and  also a beginner in it.

Comment: its done !!! i got the solution  using angular js {{ expression }} !! :)  thank you for your help .

Comment: The `href="tel:XXX"` gives an error in iOS simulator for iPhone saying that no handler found for URL. What is the way to get around this?

Comment: You need to put `<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>` in your `config.xml` for `<platform name="ios">` see [whitelisting](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html) for more...